# Is the answer 8486 to "Was the Noah flood global or local?" plagiarised?

Tags: discussion, answers, plagiarism

Is [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/8486/3487) answer to [Was the Noah flood global or local?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/7424/3487) plagiarised?

The problem is that the other sources of this exact content of this answer are timed too close to when it was submitted here.

The answer in question was submitted on 2013-06-14 05:24:45Z

[This](http://www.sunniforum.com/forum/showthread.php?62484-Noah-s-Flood-%28Local-or-Global%29-Questions&s=9546043a2bbb32e6398a15d4278a4d60&p=938382&viewfull=1#post938382) was 14-06-2013, 05:21 AM

[Here](http://forums.understanding-islam.com/archive/index.php/t-11135.html) it was 14th June 2013, 05:20 (seem to be the same user)

And we don't have the time for [this](http://www.answeringislamicskeptics.com/case-for-a-local-flood.html) which could be the original source.

What should we do about this and similar situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google, this text was cached on February of 2010, three years *before* it was posted here:

[image: Google-Fu FTW]

It of course doesn't prove that the same author wasn't involved in both, and as far as I know the timestamp represents *first* cache and not necessarily the date of last modification, but on the surface it appears to be a clear-cut case of plagiarism.

Comment: thanks. I am interested to know how you could find the date 2010?

Comment: @BattleofKarbala http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15580278?noredirect=1#15580278

Comment: @BleedingFingers OK thanks. my problem was that my javascript was disabled and so the date stamp was not shown.

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaning towards calling it plagiarized (pretty positive it is plagiarised from the last link stated in the question) and have it deleted and leave a link to this meta discussion in the comment. If the author proves that is was his/her original content then we could undelete it.

Secondly by deleting we aint taking away valuable information off the internet. It's available elsewhere we don't need it here.

Comment: I have deleted the answer for now.